# What are some tablets that can run Ubuntu?

Tags: tablet, ubuntu-touch

I can't believe I'm actually asking this, but what are some good, cheap tablets that can run Ubuntu? I'm considering getting a tablet, but I don't really want an expensive one like an iPad. And I love Ubuntu. So what tablets are out there that are cheap, but can also run Ubuntu 12.04 without much lag if it's installed after purchase? Personal anecdotes would be appreciated! Note: I'm not asking you to help me shop, just to formulate a list of tablets (+personal preference) that can use Ubuntu.

Comment: They don't exist (yet). All the good, cheap ones run *Android* (which is based on Linux).

Comment: I know there are none that come WITH Ubuntu 12.04, but I'm trying to ask IF one can run 12.04, what would the best option be? I know it's possible.

Comment: The good ones aren't cheap...you're basically looking at 10.1" x86 tablets (Intel Atom-based)

Comment: Yea they don't exist yet. [vavaldi](http://makeplaylive.com/) (or earlier called spark) is a tablet based on KDE plasma

Answer (score 13):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation

What you will need

```
Nexus 7 Tablet (8GB or 16GB)
Standard MicroUSB Cable (should come with the device)
Ubuntu Nexus 7 Desktop Installer installed on your development system
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS or Later
```

Optional

```
Micro USB Host Cable (OTG Cable) - used for attaching keyboard, mouse, etc.
```

Ubuntu Nexus 7 Desktop Installer

A simple graphical installer has been provided, and is available in a PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-nexus7/ubuntu-nexus7-installer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-nexus7-installer
```

[Usage instructions for the installer are provided in this link.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation)

[image]

Comment: "I need a few more chars to submit..." no you need to create an answer and not dump a link :) Let me explain this with an edit.

Comment: See does that not look a lot better than just a link? @alex

Comment: I've been looking into this lately and, from what I've found, running the Ubuntu installer on the Google Nexus 7 tablet looks like the most attractive solution. Note that it does not work on the Nexus 10 because that uses a different SoC.

Answer (score 9):

I am now using Ubuntu 12.04 on my Samsung Slate 7 tablet. This is quite expensive, but it's because it's a notebook. i5 quad core, 4GB ram etc. The result is super-nice. Luckily, I had chances to install Linux on quite many tablets since 2003. Until now, Slate7 + Ubuntu 12.04 is the best.

Comment: Good answer! Welcome to askubuntu. You should add a username though. Additionally, any of the intel windows 8 tablets should be able to run ubuntu.

Answer (score 5):

SmartQ T20 can dualboot Ubuntu 12.04 and Android 4.0.4. Hardware acceleration is not working but it is still useable.

Answer (score 4):

Tablets so far do not come with Ubuntu natively installed on them.  However, there are many out there that have workarounds.

For instance, my tablet is the discontinued HP Touchpad.  Using moboot, I have Ubuntu 11.10 booting natively.  Though there are some glitches when you go this route since the tablet was never designed to run a full featured Operating System (for instance, Ubuntu on the HP Touchpad has wireless driver issues if you are connecting to a secured wireless router.  Open networks are fine, just not secured).

If you find a tablet you like search on Google for "tablet name" Ubuntu install and see if anything comes up. Another good website to keep on the lookout for "hacks" is the XDA developers forum.

Answer (score 3):

I think this might be a solution for you:
http://pengpod.com/products/
It's set to release in January

Answer (score 2):

If you want a *good* tablet **today**, which "can also run Ubuntu 12.04 without much lag", you're pretty much looking at x86 tablets (Intel Atom-based, mostly) that come bundled with Windows 7. I doubt you'll get one of those cheaper than the baseline iPad (USD 500).

Answer (score 2):

Writing this on a 3.5yr old Asus T91MT x86  multi-touch tablet/netbook convertible. Dual-boot 12.10 with win7. All is sweet. Bought it lightly used 3yrs ago $233.

Oh, and run Android apps with Bluestacks in win7.

Clever gadget. Can still find 'em. Why Asus never promoted this thing I cant imagine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the yet-to-be-released [KDE Vivaldi](http://makeplaylive.com/) tablet will be able to run Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could get a tablet running Windows 7/8 and run Wubi. You can use the keywords *"tablets running windows 7"* on any web search engine.

Comment: Why Wubi when you can Install Ubuntu?