# What tablets might Ubuntu 12.04 and Unity work on?

Tags: unity, tablet, ubuntu-touch

I have seen Ubuntu run through emulators on Android, but with lightweight environments rather than unity. I'm asking because I would like to find a cheap tablet i could possibly use in place of my current netbook. And I would prefer a full desktop operating system like Ubuntu rather than iOS or Android.

What tablets , if any might Ubuntu and Unity run on?
Or would it only run with laptop/tablets?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/163755/what-are-some-tablets-that-can-run-ubuntu?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You are very unlikely to find a "cheap" tablet to run unity, this is due to graphics I would think.

While modern tabs are quad core the processor lacks high frequency, to clarify my PC has a clock speed of 3.0gz per core but even an expensive tab will likely only have 1gz this means they can multi task but are not great a intensive prossesing and the graphics chips are just rubbish, my pc has 512 dedicated mb for graphics, laptops will be less (look up intel integrated graphics) and tabs would be lucky to have half what thew laptop has.

The result of this is that the CPU must help the GPU slowing down graphic rendering and taking resources from the OS.

I think you could easily get Ubuntu on to one but not with Unity or KDE, you would need [X](http://xubuntu.org/) or [L](http://lubuntu.net/) Ubuntu.

Alternatively check out [Fuduntu](http://www.fuduntu.org/) it uses the old Gnome 2 desktop which is fast and customizable but designed for less powerful (older) PC.

Another option is [Bhodi linux](http://www.bodhilinux.com/) with the [Enlightenment](http://www.enlightenment.org/) desktop (E17) which has a special set up for touch devices and is still Ubuntu underneath.

EDIT : You will be able to get one next year though Ubuntu 13.04 will (apparently) get a mobile version read [THIS](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/01/ubuntu-tablet-to-compete-with-android-ios) and [THIS](http://www.zdnet.com/ubuntu-tablets-smartphones-coming-in-2013-2062304640/)

Comment: Next year is 2013, as far as I know... and those documents refers to 2013 as the launching year. :) so the version will be 13.04?

Answer (score 1):

The Asus Nexus 7 is officially supported by Canonical as a developer platform only at this time.

It is not recommended for general users.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7